# defer downloading the response body when making GET reques

Tags: python, curl, libcurl, pycurl

> By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is
>   downloaded immediately. You can override this behaviour in Requests
>   module and defer downloading the response body until you access the
>   Response.content attribute with the stream parameter, described here
>   http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow

I wonder if pycurl can do the same thing.

What I want to do here is to get the direct url of a few URLs having redirections ,it would be better if this could be done asynchronously .You may see I could use HEAD to do this, but the server I am sending request to seems doesn't support HEAD, so this seems the only way I can go ,can I use pycurl do the same thing here ?

I have no experience in pycurl, as deadline of my project approaches, it would be better to show some code, thanks!!!

Comment: Why not use `requests`?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco there are 30s URLs, perhaps requests cannot get all the direct urls of the URLs in a certain time,so  the SERVER closed the connections prematurely,thus requests always raise a ConnectionError exception in my situation.

Comment: Bear in mind that requests is one of Python's most popular third-party libraries — it's somewhat unlikely you're in such a unique situation that you can't use it (especially if you're not sure why).